# While traversing an ancestor tree starting from two target nodes, can I mark nodes I've seen in recursive calls to find their lowest common ancestor?

Tags: python, tree

I'm solving a problem where we're given a `tree`, its `root` and `two target nodes` (`descendantOne` and `descendantTwo`) within the tree.

I am asked to return the `lowest common ancestor` of the two target nodes.

However, we are also told that our tree is an instance of `AncestralTree`, which is given by:

```
class AncestralTree:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.ancestor = None
```

i.e. for every node in the tree, we only have pointers going upwards to the parents (as opposed to a normal tree which has pointer from parent to child!)

My idea of solving this problem is to start from both target nodes and move upwards, marking each node that we visit. At one point, we are bound to visit a node twice, and the first time we do- this is our lowest common ancestor!

Here is my code:

```
def getYoungestCommonAncestor(topAncestor, descendantOne, descendantTwo):
    lowestCommonAncestor = None
    
    def checkAncestors(topAncestor,descendantOne, descendantTwo,descendantOneSeen,descendantTwoSeen): 
        if descendantOneSeen and descendantTwoSeen: 
            return descendantOne
        else: 
            return None
        
    while not lowestCommonAncestor:
        **lowestCommonAncestor = checkAncestors(topAncestor,descendantOne.ancestor, descendantTwo,True,False)
        if lowestCommonAncestor: 
            break
        **lowestCommonAncestor = checkAncestors(topAncestor,descendantOne, descendantTwo.ancestor,False,True)
        if descendantOne.ancestor == topAncestor: 
            pass 
        else: 
            descendantOne = descendantOne.ancestor 
        if descendantTwo.ancestor == topAncestor: 
            pass
        else:
            descendantTwo= descendantTwo.ancestor
        
    return lowestCommonAncestor
```

I have put stars ** next to the two `recursion calls` in my code, because I believe this is the issue.

As I run the recursion calls, e.g. say we have seen `descendantOne`, when I run the recursion call for `descendantTwo`, it automatically marks `descendantOneSeen` as false
in its recursion call. So this causes us to never have `descendantOneSeen` and `descendantTwoSeen` to be true.

And when I run the above code, I do get a infiniteLoop error- and I do see why.

Is there any way to amend my code to achieve what I want WITHOUT using `global variables`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it will not work like that, as `descendantOneSeen and descendantTwoSeen` is never true. But even if you would fix that part of the logic, the distance the two nodes have to their lowest common ancestor may be far apart... so you need a different algorithm.

One way is to walk to the top of the tree in tandem like you did, but then when you reach the top, continue with that reference at the **other** starting node. When both references have made this jump back down, they will have visited the exact same number of nodes at the moment they meet eachother at the common lowest ancestor.

This leads to a very simple algorithm:

```
def getYoungestCommonAncestor(topAncestor, descendantOne, descendantTwo):
    nodeOne = descendantOne
    nodeTwo = descendantTwo
    while nodeOne is not nodeTwo:
        nodeOne = descendantTwo if nodeOne is topAncestor else nodeOne.ancestor
        nodeTwo = descendantOne if nodeTwo is topAncestor else nodeTwo.ancestor 
    return nodeOne
```

This may look dodgy, as it looks like a matter of luck that these node references will ever be equal. But both `nodeOne` and `nodeTwo` references will walk from both starting points (`descendantOne` and `descendantTwo`) -- it is just the order in which they do this that is inverted. But that still means they will visit the same number of nodes by the time they visit the common ancestor the *second* time.

Here is your example graph, where the two starting nodes are **C** and **I**. I have removed some of the nodes, as they are unreachable from these two nodes, so they don't play a role:

[image]

So the idea is that we start the traversal at nodes **I** and **C**. By applying the rule that when a traversal reaches the root, it will continue from the *other* starting node, we see that from **I** we will first follow the red edges, and then the green one, while the path that starts from **C** will first follow the green edge and then follow the green edges.

From this it is clear that these two traversals will take an equal number of steps to visit both the green and the red edges (just in a different order) and so they will reach node **A** at the same time when they each visit it for the *second* time.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Trincot, always a hero! I still don't quite understand why 'the distance the two nodes have to their lowest common ancestor may be far apart' is a problem- is it because it will take long time for the alto to run if the two nodes are far apart and the tree is large? But the algo still works?

Comment: Trincot, I run into an infinite loop in some cases. For the example above, let's say nodeOne is C and nodeTwo is I; if you run your code against this, we run into an infinite loop! Because nodeOne will never equal nodeTwo!

Comment: If the two nodes belong to the same tree there is no infinite loop. For your example of I and C: nodeOne will be I-D-B-A-C-A and nodeTwo will be C-A-I-D-B-A. Since they take a step in tandem, they arrive at A at the same time. Note that they meet only the second time they get at A.

Comment: But by the code above neither nodes will == A? because when nodeOne.ancestor == A, we reassign nodeOne=descendantTwo. And same when nodeTwo.ancestor ==A, we do nodeTwo = descendantOne, so when will they be A?

Comment: For I-D-B-A-C-A  and C-A-I-D-B-A; I agree up to the C and B nodes respectively, but then at C and B, nodeOne.ancestor==topAncestor and nodeTwo.ancestor==topAncestor, so nodeOne = descendantTwo and nodeTwo=descendantOne? So they won't reach A?

Comment: I see from your comment the code had a mistake in the condition. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks Trincot! Conceptually, as you mentioned in your description I still don't quite understand why it works- although I do agree it works!

Comment: Added a bit more to my answer (could not get to it earlier due to Christmas obligations).

Comment: The original question is actually equivalent to finding an intersection of two linked lists, given that they already have an intersection and you can treat `tree_node.ancestor` to be equivalent to linked lists `list_node.next`. In the case of your problem, the intersection would be the root of your tree if there are no intersecting nodes before that.